# Using Async/Await in Lightning Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I've been trying to use the `Async/Await` syntax in my LC's controllers/helpers, but I haven't been able to. All kinds of ugly errors appear, such as this:

```
Error:(1, 1) FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION - 0Ad9E0000009vA3: org.auraframework.util.json.JsonStreamReader$JsonStreamParseException: Invalid literal value [36, 21]: 'async': Source
```

They way I have been trying to implement this feature is:

```
myHelperMethod: async function( param 1 ){
}
```

Are you guys aware of any way of implementing it or is it not possible at all? [Browsers do support it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), which is what encouraged me, but maybe the framework doesn't allow it.

Comment: Bump? I have the same question...

Comment: @BrianMiller not sure how to bump stuff lol

Answer (score 9):

There is **NO** other option to define action handlers (client-side controllers, helpers or renderers) except with the `function` keyword:

```
({
    myActionHandler: function(component, event, helper) {
        // add code for the action
    },
})
```

[Handling Events with Client-Side Controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_client_side_controller.htm)

---

Using `async function` keyword anywhere in Lightning Components is not allowed, because currently, Lightning Components support only **ES6 features**, while `async/await` is an ES8 feature. Arrow functions `=>` can be used as callbacks.

Comment: What about now in 2022?

Comment: @jbyrd After reviewing this doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_supported_es.htm

It appears Aura Components only support ES5 syntax and ES6 promises. I don't believe this will ever be updated for Aura components, however, Lightning Web Components do support this feature.